# how to use Like operator here in mysql for searching user name by his/her character?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT GP.Param_ID, GP.Value, GP.Value_Hindi, GP.Param_Type_ID, GPTM.Param_Type_Name, GPTM.Param_Type_Name_Hindi, GP.Is_Active
    FROM M_Global_Param GP
    INNER JOIN M_Global_Param_Type_Master GPTM ON GP.Param_Type_ID = GPTM.Param_Type_ID
        WHERE GP.Param_ID = IFNULL(NULL,GP.Param_ID)
    AND GP.Param_Type_ID = IFNULL(NULL,GP.Param_Type_ID)
    AND GPTM.Param_Type_Name = IFNULL(NULL,GPTM.Param_Type_Name)
    AND (GP.value IFNULL OR VALUE LIKE '%' + value+ '%')
    AND GP.Is_Active = IFNULL('1',GP.Is_Active)
    ORDER BY GPTM.param_Type_Name;
```

how to use 'like' operator in mysql for searching by user name of character.

AND (GP.value IFNULL OR VALUE LIKE '%' + value+ '%')

getting SQL syntax error this line

Comment: your problem is not `like`, it's `IFNULL`: use `(gp.value is null OR gp.VALUE like ...`

Comment: I m still getting error in this line only ..after Is null or if null

Comment: It is always nice to know what error you are getting! Try the followinq query, which is equivalent to your query:  `...WHERE not GP.Param_ID is null and not GP.Param_Type_ID is null and not GPTM.Param_Type_Name is null 
AND (GP.value is null OR VALUE LIKE concat('%',value,'%'))
AND GP.Is_Active = 1
ORDER BY GPTM.param_Type_Name;`, although your `like` will not have any effect, because it is true for absolutely every text (`abc` is always `like '%abc%'`), so I'm not sure qhat you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I want to search by name or character or any of the blanck field than display all user name and details.

Comment: Thank you Solarflare ..Your suggestion is working.